# Wordpresscustom php only running when i uncomment the echo

Tags: php, html, sql, wordpress

I made a little script in php and included it in the page.php from wordpress so it will run on every page.

Currently, the script is only running if I uncomment the

> echo "Connected succesfully";

The moment I comment it out, the script stops working...

Please see the script below.

```
<?php
ob_start();

//SQL DATABASE INIT
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "databasename";

// Create connection
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
//echo "Connected successfully";


//URL RETREIVAL
if (isset($_GET['uid']) && !isset($_GET['valid'])) {

        $urlId = $mysqli->mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['uid']);
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id= '". $urlId ."'");

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
            $url = "https://thisismywebsite.com/?valid=1&uid=". $_GET['uid'];
            header('Location:'. $url);
            ob_end_flush();
        } 
        else
        {
            $url = "https://thisismywebsite.com/?valid=0&uid=". $_GET['uid'];
            header('Location:'. $url);
            ob_end_flush();
        }
} else {
    // Fallback behaviour goes here
}

?>
```

Comment: What have you done to debug what's wrong? In which _if_ branch it goes? Do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: Commenting out an `echo` is never going to break the rest of your script. There has to be something else. How do you know that the script is not working anymore? What are you testing?

Comment: And what _exactly_ are you even trying to do here? Please explain what the purpose of this is supposed to be. There might be better alternatives, than sticking this into a script file you then include manually ... Most likely, this _should_ be solved via one of the hooks WP provides.

Comment: I know this is not supposed to break the script, but I can't explain why this happens now. When i uncomment the echo "connected succesfully, my script finds the id I entered in the database, and my url changes to https://thisismywebsite.com/?valid=1&uid=0000. This confirms it works if you look at my code. The moment I comment the echo again it stops working, my url stays the same when I enter it: https://thisismywebsite.com/?uid=0000.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: The idea of this script is that it checks the the url on every page if the "uid" is filled. When it is, it checks if the uid url variable exists in a table in my database. If it does, it has to fill another variable with "valid=1". I use a seperate wordpress extension to show a popup whenever "valid=1" or "valid=0" exists in the url. When valid is equal to zero the popup says that the id is not valid, and when valid is equal to 1 the popup says that this is a valid id.

Comment: I think you missed the Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)

Answer (score 1):

in wordpress you don't have to connect with database. just declare global $wpdb

```
   ob_start();

    global $wpdb;

   //URL RETREIVAL
    if (isset($_GET['uid']) && !isset($_GET['valid'])) {

    $urlId =$_GET['uid'];
              $result = $wpdb->$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE 
    id= '". $urlId ."'");

    if (!empty($result))
    {
        $url = "https://thisismywebsite.com/?valid=1&uid=". $_GET['uid'];
        header('Location:'. $url);
        ob_end_flush();
    } 
    else
    {
        $url = "https://thisismywebsite.com/?valid=0&uid=". $_GET['uid'];
        header('Location:'. $url);
        ob_end_flush();
    }
   } else {
     // Fallback behaviour goes here
   }
```